# What is a fraudulent impression from Flurry's terms of service

Tags: flurry

I'm reading the terms-service 
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/legal-privacy/terms-service/flurry-publishers-network.html

I can read this:
"Publisher shall not, directly or indirectly, authorize or encourage any third party to (i) generate fraudulent impressions or fraudulent clicks"

I understand the app should not encourage users to click on ads. It makes sense and I'm totally fine with that. But what are "fraudulent impressions"? How an app can create a "fraudulent impressions"? For example, if an app asks a user to see an ad (example an interstitial) in exchange for something, is it a fraudulent impression? We often see reward videos, does a reward video is a fraudulent impression? At what point asking a user to see an ad become a fraudulent impression? Worst-case scenario, offering real-life things to see an ad, is it a fraudulent impression? For example, if I draw a t-shirt to users who saw some ads, is it fraudulent impressions?

I'm just trying to understand at what point we start to create a fraudulent impression. Because I see we can create a reward video, so, when asking to see an ad and giving a reward to the user become a fraudulent impression?

Thanks

Comment: Before you receive an answer here please understand that no one, except those working for Flurry, knows the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/legal-privacy/terms-service/flurry-publishers-network.html

> Publisher shall not, directly or indirectly, authorize or encourage any third party to (i) generate fraudulent impressions or fraudulent clicks, or (ii) take similar fraudulent actions or any other actions that interfere with, disrupt or interact in an unauthorized manner with the FFP Network (or servers and networks connected thereto), **including but not limited to, through repeated manual clicks, the use of robots, scrapers or other automated query tools and/or computer generated search requests, and/or the fraudulent use of other search engine optimization services and/or software.** Flurry may terminate your account at anytime for any reason, including but not limited to because of such fraudulent activity. Publisher acknowledges and agrees that Flurry may, in its sole discretion, review impressions, click-throughs or other actions, and Publisher shall not be entitled to receive any revenue share applicable to actions that Flurry determines in its sole discretion are fraudulent or improper.

Comment: Thanks, I read that. 

So probably my question was not well asked.

Is it a fraudulent impression giving a reward when a user sees an add? Even real-life things?  For example, if I draw a t-shirt to users who saw some ads, is it fraudulent impressions?

It not written in the TOS so it looks ok, but before I implemented I want to be sure what I can do and not do. I don't want my account to get terminated because I draw a little t-shirt.